# Add leading zero to hex values in python

Tags: python, c

I have the following hex values, which i have in a file.

```
ff00 928a 6275 7474 6f6e 4c69 7374 df00
84ff 002a 8869 6e70 7574 5069 6e41 0185
426e 616d 6588 4a41 4a41 4a41 4441 8672
656c 6179 73c8 4103 4103 4103 4103 ff00
2a88 696e 7075 7450 696e 4102 8542 6e61
6d65 884e 454a 4e45 4a44 4186 7265 6c61
7973 c841 0441 0441 0441 04ff 0027 8869
6e70 7574 5069 6e41 0385 426e 616d 6585
4d41 4144 4186 7265 6c61 7973 c841 0141
0141 0141 01
```

I want to split these hex values up in single bytes like ff and add the leading zero 0x, so i can put it directly into a unsigned char array in C.

I've tried by loading the hex values into python and removed all whitespaces and afterwards setting a whitespace by every other char so they're represented as single bytes. But no matter what i can't seem to change the layout of the hex values.

Here's the code

```
    with open ("yes.txt", "r") as myfile:
        byte=myfile.read().replace('\n', '').replace(' ','')

    [byte[i:i+2] for i in xrange(1,len(byte))]

    print byte
```

print byte

Can someone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't describe what you tried, show us the code that you wrote that doesn't work and explain what it's doing wrong (desired vs. actual output, exception with traceback, just incomplete code because you're stuck on the line that says `spam = ???(eggs)`, …). See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the rest of the help on asking questions.

Comment: Sorry here's the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to read the values from a file and write them back in the new format
that is, from a file of content "ff00 928a" get a new file with the content "0xff 0x00 0x92 0x8a"
this code should do the trick:

```
with open("vals.txt") as f:
    hexVals = f.read()

with open("out.txt", "w") as g:
    for val in hexVals.split(): 
        g.write('0x' + val[:2] + " ")
        if(len(val) > 2):
            g.write('0x' + val[2:]  + " ")
```

EDIT
If the file is binary (when you print f.read() you don't see the values you give but what they represent in ascii, you can do

```
from binascii import hexlify
hexVals = hexlify(f.read())
```

see if printing this gives you a string with the hex representation of the data.
And of course, you can convert it back with unhexlify from the same module, if needed.

Comment: I think he wants commas, not spaces (because he's trying to use the result as an initializer for a C array), but obviously that's pretty easy to fix here.

Comment: The solution does not seem to work. It just give me a file with a new set of bytes in the exactly same layout as the one i gave it.

@abarnert Yes i do, but as you just said, it is easy to fix

Comment: @Peter: When I run this code, then look at `out.txt`, it looks like `0xff 0x00 0x92 …`, exactly as the answers says it should. Are you sure you're looking at the right file?

Comment: As abarnet says, it should work (there's nothing tricky here, it's the simple direct approach). also, looking at it again, it can also be slightly less ugly, as you don't need to keep f open after reading it (will fix momentarily).

Comment: @Peter, I'm sorry, but I don't think that's possible, if this script will output anything (even if not what you expect), surely it will start with '0x'. So the output that you show cannot come from this piece of code. Other than to say that there must be some confusion, I really don't know how to help you from here.

Comment: Is `C:\Python27` actually your current working directory when you run the script? If not, then `C:\Python27\out.txt` isn't the output of this program, it's some other file you created earlier. (You can check its timestamp in Explorer or with the `dir` command to see how new it is. If it's not newer than the last time you ran this program, that's your problem.)

Comment: @abarnert it is my working directory. I think that the problem is that python us opening the file with hex values as bytes instead of as a string. How is that solvable?

Comment: @Peter, if the problem is reading binary data to hex-string and back look at hexlify and unhexlify from the binascii module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html

Comment: @Peter: In Python 2.x, "as bytes" and "as a string" mean the exact same thing. There is a binary mode and a text mode, but that only affects translation of Windows newlines. So, what you're suggesting as the problem doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Peter: As with my answer, you can see Eran's answer [working online, faking the files with `StringIO`](http://repl.it/4E5).

Comment: Actually when adding the hexlify, it gives me the right hex values, but the layout of them is wrong, see http://i.imgur.com/MMjyQaz.png. But when I used it with @abarnert code, the output came out perfectly, see link http://i.imgur.com/OPMnsRo.png! Thank you, but which answer should i mark as the correct  hmm

Answer (score 2):

Your list comprehension does return something useful—a list of every pair of characters.

It does have a couple problems, though: You're returning every pair of characters, 1-2, then 2-3, then 3-4. You want to use a `step` argument to make sure the range is distinct pairs, rather than overlapping pairs. And you want to start from 0, not 1, so you don't skip the first character.

More importantly, you don't *do* anything with that list, so that isn't very helpful.

The first thing to do is assign it to a variable:

```
pairs = [byte[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(byte), 2)]
```

Now, you can use another comprehension (or an explicit `for` statement) to add the `0x` to each one:

```
c_pairs = ['0x' + pair for pair in pairs]
```

And then you can join them all up with commas:

```
c_initializer = ', '.join(c_pairs)
```

It's worth noting that you could just as easily use generator expressions instead of list comprehensions here, saving a bit of memory. And you can merge the separate steps together, too.* For example:

```
c_initializer = ', '.join('0x' + byte[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(byte), 2))
```

You probably also want to stick some braces around the string, and write it out somewhere, but I'll leave that part as an exercise for the reader; the fact that you know how to use `file.read` and `str.replace` means you can probably handle these similar tasks pretty easily.

---

<sub>* Although if you merge all the steps together, as I did, replacing the single list comprehension with a generator expression doesn't actually add any benefit anymore, because if you give `str.join` an iterator it just makes a list out of it anyway.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but wouldn't `xrange(1, len(byte), 2)` be needed? otherwise there will be overlapping pairs.

Comment: @user3267581: Yes, you need the 2 `step`, as explained in the answer, but no, you do not want a 1 `start`, as also explained in the answer.

Comment: @Peter: No it doesn't. My code as it stands doesn't output _anything at all_—as I said, I left that part as an exercise for the reader. But if you print `c_initializer`, or write it to a file, or display it in a Tkinter window, or whatever, what you get is `0xff, 0x00, 0x92, 0x8a, …`. Obviously if you instead print `byte`, you'll get the original data, while if you print the literal `"Hello"` you'll get `Hello`, but the answer to that is… don't do that.

Comment: I took your code by opening the file with hex values and applying your code on them. Afterward saving it to a new file. That was the result

Comment: @Peter: I couldn't find an online Python interpreter that lets me store files, but [here it is, faking it with StringIO](http://repl.it/4E4), and you can see that it works exactly as described. Since I can't see the code you wrote, I can't guess what you did wrong, but maybe this will help you understand how to do it right.